# solr 4.7 query with "and"

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm trying to use solr (4.7.1) select query but i cannot find any useful example. I really don't understand the logic behind solr query. The -text:, +text:, *:* !(-text:??).

I want to do a select on the field "first_name" and "last_name"

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr-4.7.1/persons/select?q=first_name:%22JOSHUA%22%20and%20+last_name:%22MCKAY%22&rows=10&sort=no_persons+asc
```

In SQL :

```
select * from persons where first_name like '%JOSHUA%' and last_name like '%MCKAY%' order by no_persons asc
```

But the result have nothing related with the query. It's more like a first_name: ? OR last_name : ?.

Also, i to use the levenshtein distance algo? I know it's something like "~30".

I had less problems to configure my database synchronization with solr than using a simple query...

schema.xml :

```
<fields>
   [....]
   <field name="first_name" type="text_name" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="last_name" type="text_name" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="full_name" type="text_name" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <copyField source="first_name" dest="full_name"/>
   <copyField source="last_name" dest="full_name"/>
   [....]
</fields>

<types>
   [....]
   <fieldType name="text_name" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index"> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="false"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true" maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query"> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="false"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
   [....]
</types>
```

Comment: I'm using this type http://pastebin.com/5a87LsQZ in schema.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
q=first_name%3A"JOSHUA"+AND+last_name%3A"MCKAY"
```

Regarding levenshtein distance algo, similar function is done with the [SpellCheckComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent), which internally uses the [Lucene SpellChecker](http://wiki.apache.org/jakarta-lucene/SpellChecker) by default, which implements Levenshtein.

Also, if you see SpellCheckComponent's configuration parameter `<str name="accuracy">0.7</str>` can be used to configure accuracy of the results returned.

Comment: There is no way to specify the distance in the select?

Comment: Yes using ~after query keyword. Found this lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Proximity Searches

Comment: Or take a look at https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_search_for_one_term_near_another_term_.28say.2C_.22batman.22_and_.22movie.22.29

Comment: I've tried `q=first_name%3A"JOSHUA"~100+AND+last_name%3A"MCKAY"~100` and it's not working. I also tested `&qs=100` and `ps=100` and not working either

Comment: ~100 placed after keywords means you want to search for those keywords within 100 word apart. For example, `"JOSHUA MCKAY"~100` will search for words JOSHUA and MCKAY within 100 word distance in the specified field. However, in your case both words needs to be searched in different fields. In this case I think fuzzy search cannot be applied. It works on one field.

Comment: Solr supports fuzzy searches based on the Levenshtein Distance, or Edit Distance algorithm. To do a fuzzy search use the tilde, "~", symbol at the end of a Single word Term. For example to search for a term similar in spelling to "roam" use the fuzzy search: `roam~`
This search will find terms like `foam` and `roams`.

Additional (optional) parameter can specify the required similarity. The value is between 0 and 1, with a value closer to 1 only terms with a higher similarity will be matched. For example: `roam~0.8`. The default is 0.5.

Comment: I hope this helped you. Let us know. Thanks.

Comment: I helped me. But i think i may have an indexation problem and/or a query problem. If i use ~ there are some results that are way too far from the original request.